# Pip wheel is building a new wheel when one is already present

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, pip, python-wheel

I'm trying to build a wheel for `pandas` at `0.17.1`. I want it to use `numpy` version `1.9.2`. I have a wheel for that version of `numpy` already built in `$PWD/wheelhouse`, and a few other `pandas` dependencies as well:

```
ls wheelhouse/
numpy-1.9.2-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl python_dateutil-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl  pytz-2015.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl  six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

However, when I tell `pandas` to build, even though I inform it of the wheelhouse folder with `--find-links`, it still builds a new wheel of `numpy`:

```
$ pip --version
pip 6.0.8 from /home/me/.pyenv/versions/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)
$ pip wheel pandas==0.17.1 --find-links=$PWD/wheelhouse
Collecting pandas==0.17.1
  Using cached pandas-0.17.1.tar.gz
[... snipped, building stuff ...]
Collecting python-dateutil>=2 (from pandas==0.17.1)
  File was already downloaded /home/me/rebuild_numpy_py3/wheelhouse/python_dateutil-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz>=2011k (from pandas==0.17.1)
  File was already downloaded /home/me/rebuild_numpy_py3/wheelhouse/pytz-2015.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.7.0 (from pandas==0.17.1)
  Using cached numpy-1.10.2.tar.gz
    Running from numpy source directory.
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil>=2->pandas==0.17.1)
  File was already downloaded /home/me/rebuild_numpy_py3/wheelhouse/six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Skipping python-dateutil, due to already being wheel.
Skipping pytz, due to already being wheel.
Skipping six, due to already being wheel.
Building wheels for collected packages: pandas, numpy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pandas
  Destination directory: /home/me/rebuild_numpy_py3/wheelhouse
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for numpy
  Destination directory: /home/me/rebuild_numpy_py3/wheelhouse
Successfully built pandas numpy

$ ls wheelhouse/
numpy-1.10.2-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl  numpy-1.9.2-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl  pandas-0.17.1-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl  python_dateutil-2.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl  pytz-2015.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl  six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

The version bound on `pandas` is `>=1.7.0`, so certainly the wheel that's there should work. So why is it building a new wheel? How can I force it to use the existing one?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how wheel works. pandas requires a `>= 1.7.0` version of numpy. You're trying to force it to look for 1.9.2 even though there's already a newer version of numpy. Even if you already have it in your wheelhouse dir, it will check PyPI for the latest version of numpy as this is what is stated in pandas' setup.py file.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't make a huge amount of sense. Pandas requires a `>= 1.7.0` version of numpy. `1.9.2` satisfies this requirement. If I have a version of numpy in scope which satisfies the version bounds, it shouldn't be necessary to fetch a new one. In particular, in my case, I *don't* want to have it fetch a new version, because I have code which needs numpy `1.9.2` to work.

Comment: That actually doesn't make ANY sense. To work around it, you can run `pip wheel numpy==1.9.2 pandas==0.17.1 --find-links wheelhouse/`. Also, take a look at https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#constraints-files